# Using user form button through selected sheets

Tags: button

I'm new here and also beginner with VBA programming.
I made a user form with more similar buttons to fill up simple characters in selected worksheet at selected row.
I don't know how to make it working on more than 1 sheet in same workbook.

When I have selected  more sheets
command perform action only at first sheet.

Macro is:

Private Sub Cmnd2o_Click()

Dim r As Long
r=ActiveCell.Row

Range ("O" & r, "Z" & r ) = "w"
Range ("AM" & r, "AX" & r) = "w"

End Sub

Hope that You will help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance
Alen